# ¿Cómo validar correctamente un input = Radio que esté seleccionado y luego pasarlo a PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, formularios, validación, radiogroup

Resulta que estoy haciendo un formulario, y lo estoy validando con JavaScript, todo bien hasta que llegó el momento de revisar los "Radio", en realidad son 3 opciones y cada una de ellas envía el formulario a direcciones distintas. todo funciona, solo que siempre agarra el valor de la primera opción, y no la seleccionada o Checked.
Quisiera saber si me pueden echar una mano.
acá les dejo el formulario HTML:

```
<form class="contact-form" onsubmit="return false">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12" id="result"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder=" Nombre:" required="" id="nombre" name="nombre">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder=" Apellido:" required="" id="apellido" name="apellido">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder=" Email:" required="" id="email" name="email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="tel" placeholder=" Teléfono:" required="" id="telefono" name="telefono">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder=" Solicitud" required="" id="mensaje" name="mensaje"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12" >
                                    <span class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"><label><input type="radio" name="destinatario" value="opcion01@icloud.com" required ><strong> País 01</strong></label></span>
                                    <span class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"><label><input type="radio" name="destinatario" value="opcion02@gmail.com" checked><strong> País 02</strong></label></span>
                                    <span class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"><label><input type="radio" name="destinatario" value="opcion03@yahoo.com"><strong> País 03</strong></label></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-gradient btn-rounded mt-4" id="submit_btn" ><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin mr-2 d-none" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Contactar</span></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

éste es el script de validación

```
    $("#submit_btn").click(function () {


    $("#submit_btn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#submit_btn span").text('Enviando');
    $("#submit_btn i").removeClass('d-none');

    var user_name = $('input[name=nombre]').val() + ' ' + $('input[name=apellido]').val();
    var user_email = $('input[name=email]').val();
    var user_phone = $('input[name=telefono]').val();
    var user_message = $('textarea[name=mensaje]').val();
    if(!document.querySelector('input[name="destinatario"]:checked')) {
          var user_destinatario = $('input[name=destinatario]').val();
          }

    var post_data, output;
    var proceed = true;
    if (user_name == "") {
        proceed = false;
    }
    if (user_email == "") {
        proceed = false;
    }
    if (user_destinatario == "") {
        proceed = false;
    }
    if (user_message == "") {
        proceed = false;
    }

    if (proceed) {
        post_data = {
            'nombre': user_name,
            'email': user_email,
            'telefono': user_phone,
            'mensaje': user_message,
            'destinatario': user_destinatario
        };
        $.post('contacto.php', post_data, function (response) {
            if (response.error) {
                output = '<div class="alert-danger" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:30px;">' + response.text + '</div>';
            } else {
                output = '<div class="alert-success" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:30px;">' + response.text + '</div>';

                $('.contact-form input').val('');
                $('.contact-form textarea').val('');
            }
        }, 'json');
});
```

como podrán observar se hace la validación y luego se envía a PHP. pero el problema es que en PHP recojo el valor de la primera opción y no de la selección de Radio.

De antemano les agradezco la ayuda que pudieran ofrecer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sustituye la validación y obten el valor del input "checkeado".

```
if($('input[name="destinatario"]:checked').length) {
    var user_destinatario = $('input[name="destinatario"]:checked').val();
}
```

Comment: ok - Gracias por contestar, ya sustituí la validación, tiene lógica, sin embargo no envió el mensaje, al parecer el valor del campo no es válido o está vacío. cabe destacar que le corregí que le faltara una ' al lado del segundo "checked"

Comment: Revisa el cambio que hice en if y dinos si te arroja algún error

Comment: en este momento estoy intentando con un "for if " a ver que sucede, comento los resultados

Comment: Amigo Jonathan, tenías razón , SOLUCIONADO. `if($('input[name="destinatario"]:checked').length) {
    var user_destinatario = $('input[name="destinatario"]:checked').val();
}` Perfectamente..!

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda oportuna, con el "for" debía hacerlo en el index llamando a una función, tu script es mas funcional y corto.